# mysql select statement with limit offset bigger than actually records

Tags: php, mysql, limit, querying

I create an mysql-statement that paginates the results using `LIMIT x, n` (where `x` is the offset and `n` the returned entries).

The offset is created using GET-Vars in the form of `page=x`.

Now Google has some strange entries in its index that come from old crawls, where the page-variable exceeds the actual amount of records in the result-set.

Means, the query created with the page variable results in something like `LIMIT 1000, 30` - but the query will only return `900` entries (since the content of the table changed meanwhile. This returns an empty result-set, of course.

Is there a way to tell mysql, that if the offset exceeds the returned records to just show the last possible result-set? I don't want to make an extra query using `COUNT()` first, since this would double the load on the mysql-server (right now I'm using `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` to determine the total amount of records the query would return without the `LIMIT`-Statement.

Comment: So you are relying on stale links ?

Comment: Is there any way you can avoid using MySQL to enforce this?  Could you put this into your business logic?

Comment: Please show us the columns in this table.

Comment: it is a problem to create another query if there is no results? Change order then and you have last records. I dont think so that is other solution, without counting records

Comment: This sounds like it's more a problem with how your paging system is setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get all requested rows, with at least one row (MySQL 5.6):

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
LIMIT 1000, 30
UNION ALL (
    SELECT *
    FROM `table`
    WHERE FOUND_ROWS() = 0
    ORDER BY `id` DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ac728/2)

Comment: I tried this query, when the first SELECT contains records that fit into the limit offset then only 1 row is returned. When the limit offset yield no results, the UNION will return 1 row on every odd call and 0 on every even call (it alternates between 0 / 1 rows when you "refresh").

Comment: Hm, that's really strange. I tested it myself now and got the same strange behaviour. It seems to work with a  `LIMIT 1000`, but not with a `LIMIT 0, 1000`, which is obviously the same. That kind of makes no sense and seems to be a bug to me. I'll investigate on this, thanks for the hint.

Comment: Yep, sadly it doesn't work.  I tried it because it seemed like a cool solution. If you get it to work or find what happens, it'd be great to know.

Comment: I forgot the parentheses around the second `SELECT`, that's why the second `LIMIT` affected the combined result instead of just the second `SELECT`. Stupid me. But I think it's working as expected now. Tested under MySQL 5.6. and also added a working SQL Fiddle.

Comment: This time the first SELECT works as intended when there are records (the offset isn't too large). When the offset is too big and first one returns no records, I still get alternating results for the select in the UNION (1 row first time, 0 rows 2nd time and so on).

Comment: That's strange, cauz in [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ac728/3) it's working even with two SELECTs. Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: I ran the query on `5.5.41-MariaDB-1~precise` and on `5.6.19-0ubuntu0.14.04.1` and both yield the same result as described above. SQLFiddle gives the correct result for `5.6` but no records for `5.5`.

Comment: This sounds interesting - I'll try it... thanks a ton!